# Does mule take its dependencies or project's dependencies first?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a web service that Iam deploying in Mule. My webservice has a jackson jar version 1.9.7. However, mule 3.1.1 that iam using has a jackson 1.3.0 in its lib. So, which jackson jar would be taken at runtime. is it 1.9.7(that is project/lib) or 1.3.0(that is in mule/lib)

Comment: This most likely depends on the webserice's classpath.  The best bet is to remove the 1.3.0 jar from the mule lib (and hope it still works).  Alternatively, if the package/class names have changed enough between the versions, you might be able to live with both side-by-side

Comment: when i remove out 1.3.0 jar that is in mule/lib...iam not able to deploy the webservice in mule.

Comment: regarding the classpath, i see that there is jackson-1.9.7 in project/gradleDependencies, but did not find it in project/buildpath